# An implicit MessagesProvider instance was not found. Java Play Framework 2.8

Tags: java, playframework

I'm having a problem injecting FormFactory to my Controller, when I try to pass the Form to the view it gives me a compilation error "An implicit MessagesProvider instance was not found.  Please see https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/ScalaForms#Passing-MessagesProvider-to-Form-Helpers".

ProjectController.java

```
package controllers;

import java.util.List;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import models.Project;
import play.data.Form;
import play.data.FormFactory;
import play.mvc.*;
import play.twirl.api.Content;
import views.html.Project.*;


public class ProjectsController extends Controller implements ControllerInterfase{
    private Form<Project> projectForm;

    @Inject
    public ProjectsController(FormFactory formFactory) {
        this.projectForm = formFactory.form(Project.class).withDirectFieldAccess(true);
    }

    // Create - Crea un modelo
    @Override
    public Result create() {
        return ok((Content)create.render(projectForm));
    }

}
```

create.scala.html

```
@import helper._

@(projectForm : Form[Project])  
@layout("Create Project"){
        <main>
            @form(action = routes.ProjectsController.store()){
                @inputText(projectForm("id"))
                @inputText(projectForm("owner_id"))
                @inputText(projectForm("name"))

                <input type="submit" value="Create">
            }

        </main>

}
```

Project.java (model)

```
package models;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import io.ebean.Finder;
import io.ebean.Model;

@Entity
public class Project extends Model{

    public Project() {}

    @Id
    public Integer id;
    public Integer owner_id;
    public String name;


    public static Finder<Integer, Project> find = new Finder<>(Project.class);


}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The answer, at least for me, was found in the example [play-java-forms code](https://github.com/playframework/play-samples/blob/2.8.x/play-java-forms-example/app/controllers/WidgetController.java)

Specifically:

1) Injecting MessagesApi into the controller:

```
@Inject
    public MyController(FormFactory formFactory, MessagesApi messagesApi) {
...
    }
```

2) Adding the implicit parameter to the view:

```
@(form: Form[MyForm])(implicit request: Http.Request, messages: play.i18n.Messages)
```

3) Passing it to the implicit parameter on the form:

```
public Result create(Http.Request request) {
        Form<MyForm> form = formFactory.form(MyForm.class);
        return ok(views.html.example.render(form, request, messagesApi.preferred(request)));
}
```